# Is there any a need to separate physical Ethernet port per clients in a server side?

Tags: ethernet

Let's assume a physical server has multi-Ethernet port.

When it handle clients, Is it effective to separate physical Ethernet port for connections?

For example, If I have 1000 client, 200 clients to physical Ethernet port1, another 200 to  physical Ethernet port2.....

If it is effective, how much traffic is proper for a physical port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the application this could be done in different ways. But first, the only reason to do this is if you have a bottleneck in the network bandwidth and for example, if the LAN is GbE, that 1 Gbps is not enough. Usually, in web services the bottlenecks are found in CPU or memory first, and many times in disk access in the database. So using 3 NIC's in a multihome server for receiving requests may be unnecessary in this case.

If you have an application where bandwidth is the bottleneck, using 3 NIC's could be useful. But the problem is how to use them to balance the load generated by clients. One way is to assign 3 different IP addresses to the 3 NIC's and balance load with a load balancer among those IP addresses or with DNS and round robin policy. Other way is to use interface bonding (http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/linux_unix/article.php/3850636/Understanding-NIC-Bonding-with-Linux.htm) where all three NIC's are seen as one interface.

Other case where you may want to use different interfaces is if you have different applications using too much bandwidth, for example replicating data received a high rate. In this case each application could use different Ethernet interfaces.